# Ruby, Gem, Jekyll suddenly not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I've purchased a new laptop and I'm in the process of installing ruby and jekyll...  After I installed ruby+dev everything was fine.  Then all of a sudden it didn't know what 'gem' or 'jekyll' was?  I now receive the following message...

gem : The term 'gem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

in the powershell on win10.  Is this a path problem?  If so what's the easiest way to fix it?

Comment: to clear things up, did youuse Rubyinstaller?

Comment: Yes...  I used ruby x64 with dev tools.  I retried two more times.

Comment: it seemed to work fine the first time.  Something I changed?

Comment: try to find  Windows environment variables. There should be mention of gem, as far as I know. Sorry I am not using Windows